# Whats the difference between these two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.sname
FROM   student S,
       enrolled E1,
       enrolled E2,
       class C1,
       class C2
WHERE  S.snum = E1.snum
       AND S.snum = E2.snum
       AND E1.cname <> E2.cname
       AND E1.cname = C1.NAME
       AND E2.cname = C2.NAME
       AND C1.meets_at = C2.meets_at;
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.sname
FROM   student S
WHERE  S.snum IN (SELECT E1.snum
                  FROM   enrolled E1,
                         enrolled E2,
                         class C1,
                         class C2
                  WHERE  E1.snum = E2.snum
                         AND E1.cname <> E2.cname
                         AND C1.meets_at = C2.meets_at);
```

both the queries are executing and showing output
The first query is showing output as empty set while the second query is showing some non empty output

I thought both the queries will give me the same and correct output but only second query is showing correct result.
Can anyone please explain whats the difference between both the queries?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, this question is going to be a non-starter for this community. You should ALWAYS use explicit join syntax instead of listing tables.

Comment: What are we supposed to answer other than quote the definitions of the operators? Why do you claim they should be the same? PS This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no join relationship specified between the "Es" and the "Cs" in the second query so that's going to be a cross join (everything matches with everything). You have this in the first query and nothing comparable in the second:

```
       AND E1.cname = C1.NAME
       AND E2.cname = C2.NAME
```